# Neo4j - Deleting Indexes with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, spatial

When I create a spatial index the result is actually 2 neo indexes: a lucene "exact" index and  a spatial one.

This is pretty much a general neo question but i've encountered the issue while using the spatial extension.

I'd like to programatically delete both indexes.

With cypher I can clear up the rtree graph fine and all the nodes it has modelled, but the neo indexes remain and are now garbage representing a map layer that no longer is important.

Can I delete indexes with Cypher?

Otherwise, how is this done?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved @noisyboiler?

Comment: I did not. but this was a "legacy" index issue I think.... new style indexes I believe you can drop with cypher. and my problem went away as I moved up Neo versions.

Answer (score 2):

noisyboiler,

This is a curious one. There is a REST call to delete an index.  It is

```
DELETE http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/{index name}
```

When made against a "spatial" index you provide the layer name as the index name. This call will actually delete all of the RTree nodes, and I assume that it empties the indexes as well, but it doesn't delete them. This appears to be a glitch.

Grace and peace,

Jim